# Reading a Checkbox from a PDF using IText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I am attempting to automate reading a PDF form with interactive fields using C# and IText7 in Visual Studio. I'm using IText but for some reason my textbox fields read fine but the checkbox fields do not. The field names and types are as follows:

```
Type     | Name      | Value | ExportValue/Choice | Checked/Selected
Text     | F Name    | John  |                    | 
Text     | L Name    | Doe   |                    |
Checkbox | Enrolled  |       |       On           |       False
Checkbox | Expired   |       |       On           |       True
```

I perform a TryGetValue on the text boxes and since they have values that works just fine but the checkboxes don't get a value but have data in Checked/Selected. How do I get the True or False status from these checkboxes?

```
using iText;
using iText.Kernal.Pdf;
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Forms.Fields

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("file.pdf"));

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

PdfFormField toSet;
fields.TryGetValue("Enrolled", out toSet);
var x = toSet.GetValueAsString();
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes in pdf are customizable, therefor the expected result is not known upfront.
You can query this information to deter the state:

```
var checkedValues = field.GetAppearanceStates().Where((v) => !v.Equals("Off"));
bool isSelected =  (checkedValues.Contains( field.GetValueAsString()));
```

GetAppearanceStates retrieves all the customised states, if unchecked is one of them, it must be of value "Off". So all other values are checked.